# Mysql query with wildcard on number strings

Tags: sql, mysql, wildcard

I am trying to query a mysql table which contains strings of numbers
(i.e. '1,2,3,4,5').

How do I search to see if it has '1' but not '11' bearing in mind if it is '9,10' '9%' doesnt work??

Fixed!

```
(field like '10' OR field like '%,10,%' OR field like '%,10' OR field like '10,%')
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but in podcast #44 Joel and Jeff talk about why it's weird that you cannot use Regular expressions within SQL. RegExp's would help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the function [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-functions.html#id1242404). Btw, '9%' should work, if the column contains the values you specified, are you sure you're querying

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '9%'?
```

Comment: '9%' definitely doesnt work have tried it direct into CLI, on the sun site is says that numbers dont work correctly with wildcards 9% would pick up 9 or 900 but not 9,10

Comment: ah ha, I didnt use LIKE I used =

Comment: I'm running mysql version 5.0.70 and just tried it - it works. What type is the column?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the function find_in_set

```
select find_in_set('1','1,2,3,11,12')
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL can do it as well:

```
...
WHERE 
  ',' + SetValue + ',' LIKE '%,1,%' 
  AND ',' + SetValue + ',' NOT LIKE '%,11,%'
```

This expression cannot make use of an index, therefore performance will degrade quickly as the table size rises.

For better performance your table should be properly normalized, e.g.

```
SetId  SetValue
    1  1
    1  2
    1  3
    1  4
    1  5
```

instead of

```
SetId  SetValue
    1  '1,2,3,4,5'
```